# Can't import own packages in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, sys.path

I'm having some trouble importing own packages in my programs, and so I made a test folder to try and understand what I'm doing wrong.

It's the simplest of things, But I still can't get it to work.

This is my folder structure:

```
test
> pack1
  > __init__.py
  > mod1.py
> pack2
  > __init__.py
  > mod2.py
```

Both `init`-files are empty.

`mod1` looks like this:

```
def foo():
    print "hello"
```

and `mod2` looks like this

```
from pack1.mod1 import *

foo()
```

When running the code in PyCharm, everything works fine! But when trying to execute from cmd I get `ImportError: No module named pack1.mod1`

Is `sys.path.insert(0, "../pack1")` my only option, or is there another reason why cmd will not cooperate?

Comment: How exactly do you execute your code in command line?

Comment: @Alik `(Documents)/test/pack2> python mod2.py`

Comment: "Is sys.path.insert(0, "../pack1") my only option" No, you can also use ``sys.path.apend("/path/to/pack1/)``. And first ``import sys``, but that should be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of version, python has to know where to look for packages. Manipulating `sys.path` is a quick and dirty option, which will break sometimes in the future, if your code grows more complex. Try making a package and install it via `pip install -e` or `python setup.py develop`

(Look for this at the nice [distutils introduction](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/introduction.html))

Comment: "Manipulating sys.path is a quick and dirty option" thumbs up for this, but during the development it can be handy for testing purposes.

Comment: when you start adding code just to accomodate this, the day will come when exactly this additional code will bite you... been there, done that

Comment: Isn't it just easier to add pack1 into the Lib folder, or is this also likely to bite someone back?

Comment: @knitti I liked this one, except that I've never created a full package. Do you know of any good tutorials?

Comment: @knitti Or is it as simple as just having an `__init__.py`? (With the proper folder structure?)

Comment: @Noble Mushtak: using the Lib folder is like using undocumented features: it probably works, but you don't know if there are unintended consequences

Comment: Oh...Well, I've always used the Lib folder to add new libraries to Python because I thought it was easier than using pip. Thank you for telling me this!

Comment: @Noble Mushtak: You probably have complate control over your own python installation, but when you start having a little bit of user base, you have to actually have an installer, at which point using `pip` and `setup.py` is waay easier

Answer (score 0):

In regular Python, there are only certain folders that are checked for importing packages and the `test` folder you have doesn't seem to be one of those files. To change this, edit `sys.path` in `mod2.py` and *then* import `pack1.mod1`.

`mod2.py`

```
import sys
# Add test folder to sys.path
sys.path.append("../")

from pack1.mod1 import *
# Prints "hello"!
foo()
```

Also, instead of editing `sys.path`, you could add the `pack1` folder into the `Lib` folder within your Python directory. This will work because this is, by default, one of the folders in `sys.path`.

```
Python 2.7
  > Lib
    > pack1
      > __init__.py
      > mod1.py
```

`mod2.py`

```
from pack1.mod1 import *
# Prints "hello"!
foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you execute it via: `(Documents)/test/pack2> python mod2.py`

Problem is that `pack2.mod2.py` doesn't know where `pack1` is.

Execute it as module:
`(Documents)/test> python -m pack2.mod2`

Comment: Did not know of `python -m`, that's handy! But I need this to work via imports; This is just a test to show my problem, but I need `import` to work correctly for a bigger project.

Comment: For a bigger project I would create a package and install it via pip

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to modify scripts or directory layout you can use `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable.

Example

```
vagrant@h:/tmp/test/pack2$ python mod2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mod2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pack1.mod1 import *
ImportError: No module named pack1.mod1
vagrant@h:/tmp/test/pack2$ export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/tmp/test"
vagrant@h:/tmp/test/pack2$ python mod2.py
hello
vagrant@h:/tmp/test/pack2$
```

More about searching modules - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path